# Custom response from JQuery UI DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to add a button to a JQuery DatePicker that would give a customized response (that is not a date).  My situation is a form asking previous work experience, and I want a `Present` button with the DatePicker on the `employment_date_end` field.

Comment: I can't help with the actual question, but if you don't manage to solve it this way the way I've normally seen this done is to have a "is current employer" checkbox which can be selected and hides the end date field. Or just have a note saying leave end date blank if current employer.

Comment: Thanks, both those ideas sound really good, I think if I spend much more time on this without a solution I will fall back on one of those

Comment: This would be possible if the `create` event handler actually worked correctly.

Comment: @Andrew yeah, I totally got stuck wasting time on that :p

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<button>Present</button>").appendTo($('<div class="ui-datepicker-buttonpane ui-widget-content" />').appendTo(".ui-datepicker")).button()
```

this script adds the button to date picker when shown u can call this script on events like on show event of date picker.To try it just open firebug open datepicker popup and execute the script in firebug console and the button will be added its just a simple fix that i m giving .there are many other ways like extending datePicker

Comment: You should try this in code, keep in mind the `create` event doesn't work, so there is no point when you can initialize this.

Comment: You can use onload of jquery  and run this code or simply extend the component and add this code there in extended class